# How do I use Netsuite's "Import CSV Records" feature to create a Bill Payment?

Tags: csv, import, payment, netsuite

Can anyone provide a CSV template for importing a CSV vendor payment? I would like to pay specific bills for specific vendors by importing a CSV file with the list of bills. I am getting stuck with proper field mapping and required fields. Please help. Thank you.

See my progress: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCLX6.png

Chris

Comment: The error I am currently getting is: "Unable to find a matching line for sublist apply with key: [doc,line]."

Comment: Can you show some code please?

Comment: I am not using any code. Just a CSV file, shown here: http://i.imgur.com/TesJgAJ.png

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an open bill with the same id as what is in your csv file?  Also check if the bill and your bill payment have the same vendor and account information.